# Supervisor does not initialize parameters succeed

Tags: tensorflow, initialization, supervisord

It throws an exception when I tried to initialize parameters with `tf.train.Supervisor` where the net is constructed with tensorlayer. The code is like this:

```py
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=FLAGS.summary_dir, save_summaries_secs=0, saver=None)
with sv.managed_session(config=config) as sess:
       init_ = sess.run(init_op)
       net.print_params()
       net.print_layers()
        tl.layers.print_all_variables()
```

and the exception is:

```py
Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/recsys/anaconda3/envs/tf1.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorlayer/layers.py", line 309, in print_params
    val = p.eval()
  File "/home/recsys/anaconda3/envs/tf1.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 463, in eval
    return self._variable.eval(session=session)
  File "/home/recsys/anaconda3/envs/tf1.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 606, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/home/recsys/anaconda3/envs/tf1.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3914, in _eval_using_default_session
    raise ValueError("Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default "
ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MainEntryPtb.py", line 65, in <module>
    train_rnn(FLAGS)
  File "/home/recsys/wangjian/learntf/TFTemplate/examples/ptb.py", line 122, in train_rnn
    net.print_params()
  File "/home/recsys/anaconda3/envs/tf1.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorlayer/layers.py", line 313, in print_params
    raise Exception("Hint: print params details after tl.layers.initialize_global_variables(sess) or use network.print_params(False).")
Exception: Hint: print params details after tl.layers.initialize_global_variables(sess) or use network.print_params(False).
```

It seems that when I run initialize op `init_ = sess.run(init_op)`  it does not really work as if parameters are initialized succeed `net.print_params()` would not throw an exception. I also tried `sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=FLAGS.summary_dir, save_summaries_secs=0, saver=None, init_op=tf.global_variables_initializer())` to initialize parameters, but it also failed.

I use tensorflow v1.2.1 and python3.6

Answer (score 0):

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14320) has clearly explained this problem.

This is not a bug, neither nor "Supervisor does not initialize parameters succeed".

You should just change your sess into `interactivesession` or use `with sess.as_default`, then this problem will be solved.

If you want to know why this problem occurs,you should refer to the tensorlayer [source code](http://tensorlayer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/tensorlayer/layers/core.html#Layer.print_params), in the definition of print_params has the :

```
val = p.eval(session=session)
```

clearly `eval` only used for interactivesession or `with sess.as_default`